# Controling what an org-link points to with variables

Tags: org-mode, variables

Let's say I have the following:

```
#+NAME: output-directory
/path/to/output/directory

Results can be found [[file+emacs:/path/to/output/directory][here]].
```

Is there a way for me to have an org link to the output directory **based on whatever the value of the output-directory variable**? Something in the lines of:

```
#+NAME: output-directory
/path/to/output/directory/

Results can be found [[file+emacs:output-directory][here]].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to define the output directory in your org-file you can use [customized link abbrevations](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Abbreviations.html) as follows.

```
#+LINK: my-output-dir file+emacs:/path/to/output/directory/

Results can be found [[my-output-dir:][here]].

Link to some [[my-output-dir:test.org][special result]].
```